# Replacement bedroom amplifier

Tags: audio, amplifiers

So recently I bought a second hand 5.1 surround sound set for the bedroom. As it turns out random people online can't always be trusted and one of the outputs on the amplifier didn't work. The set in question is the SCS-140. Seeing as I have all the speakers already bought I don't feel like purchasing an entirely new set so I've been searching for a new amplifier. I came across a few but most didn't have the connectors required. My set has the clamps to clamp the cables in place, not the plug-in connectors. Please note that I don't know much about electronics or soldering to begin with so I wouldn't know where to begin soldering connectors to the cables. Would my best bet be to just buy an entirely new set or is there a good alternate amplifier (preferably with integrated subwoofer) to replace the one with the broken output?

[image]

I should add that the system will be hooked up to my desktop or my raspberry pi (which in both cases means an aux or digital audio connection). I should also note that I do have a sound card purchased for this system which I'm connecting it to.

Comment: Which of the outputs does not work?

Comment: When connected to my phone, one of the speaker outputs doesn't seem to work. When connected via digital audio (to my pc or pi) only the receiver/sub has a tiny bit of sound.